# Do discontinuous functions have subgradients also?

Tags: neural-networks, optimization, autoencoders, variational-bayes, convex

Typically, the subgradient is defined for convex functions. And [convex functions are continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2961783/is-a-convex-function-always-continuous).

However, DeepMind's [VQ-VAE paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.00937) defines a model with a discontinuous vector quantization (VQ) layer, resulting in a discontinuous objective function. Still, the authors remark:

> One could also use the subgradient through the quantisation operation, but this simple estimator worked well for the initial experiments in this paper.

Is there a more general definition of the subgradient that would make sense here?

Comment: please ping if someone answers, I'm interested too, no clue which subgradient would make sense

Comment: @Alberto You can just "follow" questions.

Comment: lol didn't know about that button